# HTML Center Image With Text Paragraph Below

Tags: html, css, angular, image, text

I would like to display an image centered in the browser that also has a large paragraph of text below the image. I'd like the text displayed below the image aligned with the left and right boundaries of the image. The image comes from an outside service API and changes daily, sometimes in landscape and sometimes in portrait. I've reduced the image size to 75% so that it fits better on the screen.

Imagine 'I' is image, 'T' the text paragraph:

```
          IIIIIIIIIIIII
          IIIIIIIIIIIII
          IIIIIIIIIIIII

          TTTTTTTTTTTTT
          TTTTTTTTTTTTT
          TTTTTTTTTTTTT
          TTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

I have something almost reasonable looking using a table and some formatting, but I'm not convinced that it's the best solution. I'm looking for a better cleaner approach than mine.  Also I scoured around the web and stack overflow and didn't come across any solutions that really worked so far.

My current code (note the Angular variables for the image and text):

```
<h1 class="page-title">Nasa Daily Image</h1>
<br>

<div>
<p style="text-align: center;">{{_nasaImage._title}}</p>

 <div style="width: 95%; margin:0 auto; display: block;">
    <table  style="border:1px solid black; width: 95; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;"> 
                <img style="height: 75%; width: 75%;" src={{_nasaImage._imgUrl}}  alt="link broken?" >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>                    
                <p style="margin-left: 105px; margin-right: 105px; text-indent: 50px;"> {{_nasaImage._explanation}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
<div>
```

The layout of the image and the text would be similar to this:
[image: picture stacked on text]

Additional information: This is for an Angular project. The code is being rendered by the app.component.html within a "jumbotron" div that is as follows:

```
   <!-- main content container -->
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need some css to do that. Here is an [example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9dp5x3?file=src/app/app.component.css) and here is the code (**Edited with the new informations**) :

Displayer component (It will display the image and the text (can be passed as input of course):

.html :

```
<div class="displayer">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras pellentesque ornare leo, vel eleifend ante rutrum ac.
    </div>
```

.css :

```
.displayer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: transparent;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

App component :

.html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <h1>NASA DAILY IMAGE</h1>
                <p>Title of the image like "Eclipse under the Bamboo"</p>
                <app-displayer></app-displayer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note it is the App component that take care of the horizontal alignment of the `app-displayer` with `text-center` (A bootstrap class).*

Here is the result you have in the browser:
[image: Result of the code (Also visible in the stackblitz repro)]

Comment: Unfortunately, that code didn't work as intended. The image was placed at the very top of the page obscuring the menu and title bar. I'm after a layout that looks more like the layout in the question. I tried changing some options in the code sample, without much success.

Comment: I don't really understand what you need. The repro i gave you works fine on Stackblitz, the block containing the image and the text is centered **(Horizontally AND vertically, is it what you want ?)** as your question says. Can you show me what you try resulted in and reproduce it ? Or provide me more details so I can edit the answer

Comment: Hi Quentin, thanks for the reply. Your solution seems to work on a plain html page, but I should have mentioned that this is for an Angular project. My original code and the output are posted above as well as some additional information with the code block that the "jumbotron" div uses.  My code is more or less working as you can see from the image, my main question is if there is a better cleaner way to get that effect than the rather awkward solution that I cobbled together.

Comment: @Ken What I gave you IS an angular project. I really need more information about your code to help you. From what I understand of your question, there is no need for you to have an image centered horizontally AND vertically, it just need to be displayed under the text "Eclipse under the bamboo". I edited my answer to show you what I think you want. If it's incorrect, then please add a **full code and a full screenshot** so we can understand your needs.

Comment: @Ken Ok well that is not possible. You must have implemented it wrongly. You should at least have the text and image aligned. Please reproduce your problem on a stackblitz/codeSandbox or provide a github repository so I can see your project and what's wrong in it (Put it in your question so everyone can see that)

Comment: Hi Quentin, Thanks for your input. Everything you needed was in the original question. Unfortunately the solution you provided simply didn't work in my situation.  I found a solution that works for me, and hopefully it will provide some guidance to the next person with a similar question.

Comment: Ok well good to know you found a solution. Next time try to provide a repro, that is thousand time easier for us to understand, and seeing your code can help a lot (I'm 100% sure my solution does not works for you because of a part of your code that might interfer with mine or something like that).

Comment: Hi Quentin, just FYI, the solution you gave works, but only with a fixed width. When the width is a percentage, see my original question, it stops working correctly and the text doesn't line up with the image. In my case, the width of the image and the text can be variable as the image resizes. The variable width is a requirement in my case, maybe that wasn't clear in the original post. In any event, I found a solution that works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I just had to change the values from displayer's width to 75% and img width to 100% (also removed max-width, not used anymore) and it works fine. You really should think about rework your page to make it works. Using table isn't recommanded anymore (olf solution, from 2002 something liek that..). You need to learn about Flexbox, it will save you (and us trying to help you) plenty of times ;)

Answer (score 0):

After digging into this a bit more, I found a solution. Using the table layout was the correct thing to do so that the image would display above text, and the text would line up correctly on the left side below the image. The missing pieces were using some nested "div" tags and some additional formatting to get the text to display correctly. The best part about the solution is that as the page is resized, both the image and text track together. This works on both a desktop and mobile browser.

The code below is from an Angular 9 project. Just the HTML for the router-outlet, the page HTML that displays the image and text, and the data model typescript are shown.

app.component.html

```
<!-- main content container -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

image.component.html

```
<h1 class="page-title">Nasa Daily Image</h1>
<br>
        
<div>
    <p style="text-align: center;">{{_nasaImage._title}}</p>
    
    <div style="width: 95%; margin:0 auto; display: block;">
        <table  style="border:0px solid black; width: 95; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;"> 
                    <img style="height: 75%; width: 75%;" src={{_nasaImage._imgUrl}}  alt="link broken?" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <!-- ok, this works, and the text rearranges correctly when resized-->                
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 75%; text-align: start;">
                            <p style="text-indent: 50px; justify-content: flex-start;"> {{_nasaImage._explanation}}</p>          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

data-model.ts

```
export class NasaImage {

        public _copyright: string;
        public _explanation: string;
        public _title: string;
        public _date: string;
        public _imgUrl: string;

        constructor(copyright: string,
                    explanation: string,
                    title : string,
                    date : string,
                    imgUrl: string)
        {
            this._copyright = copyright;
            this._explanation = explanation;
            this._title = title;
            this._date = date ;
            this._imgUrl = imgUrl;

        }
}
```

As with all code samples, your mileage may vary.

Here is a working example of the output:

[image]